# Getting selected items from Silverlight RadTreeView

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radgridview

I hope I'm not missing an existing question, but I couldn't find it with some searching.  In my project I have a RadTreeView showing a multi-level hierarchy of data.  The control is set to tri-state mode.  If a user clicks a lower-level item, it checks the parents (full check or dash check as necessary):

```
[-]
 - [] Item 1
 --- [] Sub-Item 1-1
 - [*] Item 2
 --- [*] Sub-Item 2-1
```

In this example, I checked Sub-Item 2-1.  The parent Item 2 is properly checked since all children are checked, the root node has a dash to indicate that something is checked lower down.  The problem is that the CheckedItems collection contains three entries with no way to determine the difference between checked or indeterminate.  Internally there is a collection called itemtogglestatestorage which has exactly what I need (item and state) but no way to get this through the public interface.  Am I missing something obvious?  What is the recommended way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it`s better to work with data here, not with UI elements. Check state should correspond to some property of databound object.
Telerik docs have a nice example of such binding here: [Bind RadTreeViewItem CheckState Property](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radtreeview-howto-bind-checkstate-property.html) (this is WPF doc but applies the same to SL and it`s cleaner than [SL version](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreeview-howto-bind-checkstate-property.html))

The only change you have to do is to replace `bool` with `bool?` since you should have 3 states now, and add `ToggleState.Indeterminate` to both conveter methods from this doc page. Then you`ll be able to get item state no problem from objects themselves!